# Simple logic in .bat file?

Tags: loops, batch-file, nested, goto

I have the need to run a .bat file to run a SQL command on demand, It needs to have an `if` nested within a `for` and the `if` should repeat until true.

What I have:

```
@echo off
cd "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Scripting\"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('type queue.txt') DO (
:loop

  IF EXIST reset.sql (

  goto loop

  ) ELSE (

  ::Create SQL command
  echo USE dbname> reset.sql
  echo EXEC dbo.sp_ResetSubscription @ClientName = '%%a'>> reset.sql
  echo EXEC dbo.sp_RunClientSnapshot @ClientName = '%%a'>> reset.sql
  sqlcmd -i "reset.sql"

  if exist reset.sql del /f /q reset.sql
  )
)
if exist queue.txt del /f /q queue.txt
```

This bombs out when it hits the loop, if I move :loop from where it is to within the if statement it works fine, however that isn't much use.

What I need it to do is to keep looping until `reset.sql` does not exist but at the same time stay within the same iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not ever GOTO a :label within a parenthesized block of code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8481978/1012053 - it deals with an IF() block, but the concept is the same for a FOR..DO() block. Performing a GOTO within a FOR..DO() will abort the remainder of the FOR iterations *NOTE - a FOR /L loop will silently finish counting without actually processing the DO() clause*

This modification should give you the behavior you are looking for.

```
@echo off
cd "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Scripting\"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('type queue.txt') DO (
  call :waitForNoReset
  ::Create SQL command
  echo USE dbname> reset.sql
  echo EXEC dbo.sp_ResetSubscription @ClientName = '%%a'>> reset.sql
  echo EXEC dbo.sp_RunClientSnapshot @ClientName = '%%a'>> reset.sql
  sqlcmd -i "reset.sql"
  if exist reset.sql del /f /q reset.sql
)
if exist queue.txt del /f /q queue.txt
exit /b

:waitForNoReset
  if exist reset.sql goto :waitForNoReset
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
@echo off
cd "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Scripting\"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('type queue.txt') DO (
:loop

  IF NOT EXIST reset.sql (

     ::Create SQL command
     echo USE dbname> reset.sql
     echo EXEC dbo.sp_ResetSubscription @ClientName = '%%a'>> reset.sql
     echo EXEC dbo.sp_RunClientSnapshot @ClientName = '%%a'>> reset.sql
     sqlcmd -i "reset.sql"

     if exist reset.sql del /f /q reset.sql
     goto endIter
   ) 

  goto loop
  :endIter 
 )

if exist queue.txt del /f /q queue.txt
```

Comment: That will not work for the same reasons the original will not work. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9018647/1012053)