# ( was unexpected at this time - batch script

Tags: scripting, batch-file

I'm using the batch script below and get an error

> ( was unexpected at this time.

I know that the problem is in the first line but I don't understand what is wrong.
Any ideas ?

script:

```
IF [%1]==[] (
    :LOOP1
    SET /P isDefault=Value Missing, do you want to use default values [1,1,10,Local      Area Connection 2]?[y/n]
    IF %isDefault%==y (
        SET from=1
        SET step=1
        SET to=10
        SET lan="Local Area Connection 2"
        GOTO :USERLOOP
    )
    IF %isDefault%==n GOTO :END
    GOTO :LOOP1 
)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, the problem is *not* on the first line.

The problem is that `cmd` does variable substitution immediately when it parses the `IF` statement, including its body.  Therefore the line:

```
IF %isDefault%==y (
```

is problematic because `isDefault` isn't set when the outer `IF` statement is parsed, so it becomes:

```
IF ==y (
```

and hence you get the error about `(` being unexpected.  You can get around this by enabling the command extension (`SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`) for *delayed environment variable expansion* (see `set /?` for details).  You also can rewrite your script:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%1"=="" GOTO :EOF

:LOOP1
SET /P isDefault=Value Missing, do you want to use default values [1,1,10,Local Area Connection 2]?[y/n]
IF "%isDefault%"=="y" (
    SET from=1
    SET step=1
    SET to=10
    SET lan="Local Area Connection 2"
    GOTO :USERLOOP
)
IF "%isDefault%"=="n" GOTO :EOF
GOTO :LOOP1
```

(I made some other changes, such as using the built-in `:EOF` label instead of `:END`.)

Comment: You dramatically changed the intended behavior with your first IF statement. I can't be sure, but it should probably read `IF NOT "%~1"=="" GOTO :USERLOOP`. You are assuming there is no code after the `:END` label - perhaps there is cleanup code at the end that must be performed, so `GOTO :EOF` may not be correct.

Comment: @dbenham: Argh again.  I did mean `IF NOT` on the first line.  That's what I get for answering in a rush.  Yes, I made some assumptions about `:END`; hard to say without seeing more of the script.

Comment: Still not correct - I think it should GOTO :USERLOOP. If parameters are provided, then the batch goes directly to the functioning part of the code (:USERLOOP). Otherwise it enters the default parameter processing before possibly going to :USERLOOP.

Answer (score 4):

As jamesdlin said, it's a problem with empty variables and also with delayedExpansion.
Then the solution is simple by replacing `%isDefault%` with `!isDefault!`, this works even if isDefault is empty.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
IF [%1]==[] (
    :LOOP1
    SET /P isDefault=Value Missing, do you want to use default values [1,1,10,Local      Area Connection 2]?[y/n]
    IF !isDefault!==y (
        SET from=1
        SET step=1
        SET to=10
        SET lan="Local Area Connection 2"
        GOTO :USERLOOP
    )
    IF !isDefault!==n GOTO :END
    GOTO :LOOP1 
)
```

Comment: Jeb - how naughty of you preserving that goto label within an IF block :) I realize that the code will work fine as written. But choppy will get a rude surprise if he/she thinks this is ok, and then does the same when there is an ELSE clause. @choppy - read this question and my answer to see what I am referring to: [(Windows batch) Goto within if block behaves very strangely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481558/windows-batch-goto-within-if-block-behaves-very-strangely)

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem and code construct that was causing me a lot of pain to resolve. My error message was **". was unexpected at this time"**...

It took me a couple long days to figure out another similar consideration due to this problem... Please take a look a the following problem and subsequent solution here: [". was unexpected at this time" generated from batch script line 'if exist [file] (...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280217/was-unexpected-at-this-time-generated-from-batch-script-line-if-exist-file/47280406#47280406)

The solution was simply the treatment of '(' and ')' on ECHO lines inside an IF statement block.

The point is, do consider treatment of special characters as a possible source of a problem when troubleshooting IF (and possibly FOR) statements.

HTH someone...