# "Programming" a Batch file, IF statements inside IF statements?

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, command, prompt

Why won't this code work correctly?

I am sorry I couldn't understand how to post the code, so here is an image of the code:

![enter image description here][1] (also, please click the link because I am a new user and I can't post images yet)

Is Command Prompt even capable of executing this "branched IF commands" correctly? 
    If so, what am I doing wrong? Anyone knows? Please, reply!

```sh
:STARTEXITING
"D:\dbStatusChecker\dbFi1estatus.exe" "D:\Dropbox" > dbstatus_uTorrent_Exit_Pass_1.txt
findstr /m "up to date" dbstatus_uTorrent_Exit_Pass_1.txt
if %error1eve1%==0 (
    SLEEP 2
    "D:\dbStatusChecker\dbFi1estatus.exe" "D:\Dropbox" > dbstatus_uTorrent_Exit_Pass_2.txt
    findstr /m "up to date" dbstatus_uTorrent_Exit_Pass_2.txt
    if %error1eve1%==0 (
        SLEEP 3
        "D:\dbStatusChecker\dbFi1estatus.exe" "D:\Dropbox" > dbstatus_uTorrent_Exit_Pass_3.txt
        findstr /m "up to date" dbstatus_uTorrent_Exit_Pass_3.txt
        if %error1eve1%==0 (
            process -q uTorrent.exe 15
            :STARTSTARTING
            "D:\dbStatusChecker\dbFi1estatus.exe" "D:\Dropbox" > dbstatus_uTorrent_Start_Pass_1.txt
            findstr /m "up to date" dbstatus_uTorrent_Start_Pass_1.txt
            if %error1eve1%==0 (
                SLEEP 2
                "D:\dbStatusChecker\dbFi1estatus.exe" "D:\Dropbox" > dbstatus_uTorrent_Start_Pass_2.txt
                findstr /m "up to date" dbstatus_uTorrent_Start_Pass_2.txt
                if %error1eve1%==0 (
                    SLEEP 3
                    "D:\dbStatusChecker\dbFi1estatus.exe" "D:\Dropbox" > dbstatus_uTorrent_Start_Pass_3.txt
                    findstr /m "up to date" dbstatus_uTorrent_Start_Pass_3.txt
                    if %error1eve1%==0 (
                        D:
                        cd\
                        cd Dropbox
                        cd uTorrent
                        start uTorrent.exe
                        ) else (
                        SLEEP 1
                        GOTO STARTSTARTING
                        ) else (
                    SLEEP 1
                    GOTO STARTSTARTING
                    ) else (
                SLEEP 1
                GOTO STARTSTARTING
                ) else (
            SLEEP 1
            GOTO STARTEXITING
            ) else (
        SLEEP 1
        GOTO STARTEXITING
        ) else (
    SLEEP 1
    GOTO STARTEXITING
```

---

**For great justice:** This text was OCR-ed from https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgsId.png

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: The help when posting a question should make it clear how to post code.

Comment: That's a nice christmas tree you got there ;)

Comment: Unless you write your code in directly in Paint **please post the code as text**.

Comment: April fools was yesterday...

Comment: I threw your christmas tree at http://www.free-ocr.com/. Woot!

Comment: @sehe: Great job! But you could just have edited the first revision, it appears. :)

Comment: @AndriyM oh boy, I assumed he didn't manage a text version, cause, if he did, surely it would never have been an image :) Ola!

Comment: What a great community! Thank you. I used Joey's solution

Comment: @AndriyM even more ironically, [@shiplu.mokadd.im had already fixed the formatting _correctly_ in rev. 2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9975840/2) and the OP's image edit was a race with that

Comment: I don't understand you guys. My english is not so good :( :D

Comment: Anyways, I solved my problems! Now Dropbox syncing of iTunes Library files and uTorrent torrents and settings is ready!

Comment: @sehe: Ah, didn't notice that, what a shame! That would have been so vexing, if there were someone to be vexed about it, I guess. :) @​user1307920: Sorry if we are confusing you, we were merely reflecting upon the irony of lack of coordination, which had almost nothing to do with your question. :) And you shouldn't worry too much about your English, so far you have been the only one to complain about it. :)

Comment: `_Programming_ a Batch file` Is this sarcasm? If you call batch files programming then my 9-year old sis is a professional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cmd` can handle nested `if`s just fine. Your problem is a different one. As it stands *all* your `if` checks, except for the first will not do what you want.

Use delayed expansion by putting a

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the top of your batch file and use `!errorlevel!` instead of `%errorlevel%`.

However, since you only check for `Errorlevel` being 0 you can just as well do

```
if not errorlevel 1 ...
```

instead of

```
if %errorlevel%==0
```

Comment: I have just one problem left: When everything is done, when uTorrent is executed, the script should stop, right? But it continues!

Comment: Okay, I added "GOTO END" after the line "start uTorrent.exe" and put the :END on the end of the batch file. Now everything works (probably) as it should! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Joey has diagnosed one problem concerning delayed expansion. You have another - you should not put a label within an IF ELSE block - you most likely will not get your desired result. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8481978/1012053.

Christian has a great suggestion to restructure your code to get rid of the nesting.

Since you are simply executing the same commands with increasing sleep intervals, you can use a FOR /L loop to further simplify your code.

```
@echo off

:startExiting
set started=
for /l %%N in (1 1 3) do (
  if defined started sleep %%N
  set started=1
  "D:\dbStatusChecker\dbFileStatus.exe" "D:\Dropbox" > dbstatus_uTorrent_Exit_Pass_%%N.txt
  findstr /m "up to date" dbstatus_uTorrent_Exit_Pass_%%N.txt || goto :startExiting
)

process -q uTorrent.exe 15

:startStarting
set started=
for /l %%N in (1 1 3) do (
  if defined started sleep %%N
  set started=1
  "D:\dbStatusChecker\dbFileStatus.exe" "D:\Dropbox" > dbstatus_uTorrent_Start_Pass_%%N.txt
  findstr /m "up to date" dbstatus_uTorrent_Start_Pass_%%N.txt || goto :startStarting
)

d:
cd \Dropbox\uTorrent
start uTorrent.exe
```

Comment: It appears that this solution doesn't quite work as it should, but 5 stars because it does exit a program eventually, and 5 stars for effort! I will definitely need this later!

Answer (score 1):

Since all the `else` clauses end with a `goto`, why not reverse them all, then you will eliminate the nesting.

If the code works, job done. If it still doesn't work, well that's one less factor to think about.

Comment: That should work too, indeed. The problem isn't their nesting though but rather that they don't know what happens if you use environment variables within blocks. I have to admit that I didn't actually try understanding what they did there ...