# batch file simultaneous null and file output

Tags: file, batch-file, redirect

I made this batch file it works fine exceptfor submenu 4 where it redirects ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w !thyme! to NUL instead of echo ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w !thyme!>NUL to %dir101%

```
@echo off & SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
title TXTanimation
set dir101=C:\USers\%username%\Desktop\file.bat
goto label1
echo Lets make a text animation
pause
set /p dir101=where will the .bat be saved:
:label1
echo @ECHO OFF > %dir101%
echo: >> %dir101%
:menu
echo 0=Edit important information
echo 1=Display .txt
echo 2=Play sound
echo 3=Close sound player
echo 4=Add nessicary wait between .txt
echo 5=Label point
echo 6=Edit variable
echo 7=Goto point
echo 8=Create IF sentence
echo 9=End it
Set /p choose=which one:

If '%choose%'=='0' (
SEt /p title=What is the title
:LOL101
set /p color=what color do you want type test to experiment with the colors
If '!color!'=='test' goto tester
goto model
:tester
SEt /p test=Please give hexadecimal number type exit to leave:
if '!test!'=='exit' goto LOL101
color !test!
goto tester
:model
echo title %title% >> %dir101%
echo color %color% >> %dir101%
goto menu
)

If '%choose%'=='1' (
set /p dir=what is the dir of your .txt:
)
If '%choose%'=='1' (
echo cls >> %dir101%
echo type %dir% >> %dir101%
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='4' (
SEt /p thyme=How much milliseconds 250 is usual:
echo ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w !thyme!>NUL >> %dir101%
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='9' (
echo Thanks for making
pause
exit /b
)
```

Yeh It's a big program but my error is real small. I could type the template and insert the variable maybe?
But `echo ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w !thyme!>NUL >> %dir101%` I need it to state the >NUL to be redirected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to escape the redirection symbol so that it gets echoed instead of being interpreted as redirection.

```
echo ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w !thyme! ^>NUL >>%dir101%
```

Warning: your submenu 0 works as written, but you may be establishing a bad habit that will cause problems for you in the future. You generally should not put a label inside a parenthesized code block. Read [(Windows batch) Goto within if block behaves very strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481558/windows-batch-goto-within-if-block-behaves-very-strangely) for an example of how that can cause problems, and the selected answer explains why it can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly escape those commands when you are trying to echo them into another batch. Try this:

```
echo ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w ^!thyme^!^>NUL >> %dir101%
```

which writes this into your `%dir101%` batch:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w *value_of_thyme_variable* > NUL
```

the `^` escapes most functions in batch. 
FYI: this **does not** work on `%` variable values. If you need to escape a `%` variable value like `%test%` you can do it like this: `%%test%%`, but as you can see it does work for the `!` variable value above.

Comment: I don't think Jake wanted to escape `^!thyme^!`. And your attempt doesn't quite work anyway - unquoted `^!thyme^!` is still expanded. Unquoted delayed expansion must be escaped as `^^!thyme^^!`.