# Batch file goto not working in for loop

Tags: batch-file, goto, label

I have a for loop in my batch file that loops through folders. I want to skip particular folders. I can do this with an IF statement, but would prefer a GOTO like I'm showing below.

```
for /d %%F in (*) do (
 if /i "%%F"=="Archive" goto nextFolder
 REM do stuff here
:nextFolder
)
```

But the above is giving me errors:

```
) was unexpected at this time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work - you can't jump *into* a control-flow construct and expect everything to be fine.

Please take a look at [(Windows batch) Goto within if block behaves very strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481558/windows-batch-goto-within-if-block-behaves-very-strangely) for a good discussion of why this is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using GOTO, you could use NOT to exclude a folder or folders.

```
for /d %%F in (*) do (
   if /i NOT "%%F"=="ARCHIVE"
       REM do stuff here
)
```