# Batch file - Wait for file in loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a very simple bat-file.

In a for-loop I call another application which will create a file for me. When that file is generated I want to do this again until the loop has finished. I need to wait for the file to be created before I run the loop again.

I  need to use `START` and `CALL`, because after the file is created I will kill the process. It's not included in the code below, but it's needed.

```
@echo off

for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    SET filename=fooFile_%%i.txt
        START /B CMD /C CALL createFile.bat fooFile_%%i.txt

    :waitfile
        ECHO waitforfile: %filename%
        TIMEOUT /T 10 >nul
        IF EXIST %filename% GOTO FoundIt
        goto waitfile

    :FoundIt
        ECHO Found file %filename%
)
ECHO All done!
```

And my `createFile.bat`. This is actually another application. But the code below is enough to mock it:

```
@echo off

set arg1=%1
TIMEOUT /T 10 >nul
copy NUL %arg1%
ECHO Created file
```

Current output:

```
waitforfile:
waitforfile fooFile_1.txt
    1 file(s) copied.
Created file
Found file fooFile_1.txt
All done!
```

As you can see from the output I can't get the loop to work with my GOTO's. I've seen these questions:

[Batch file goto not working in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983972/batch-file-goto-not-working-in-for-loop)

[(Windows batch) Goto within if block behaves very strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481558/windows-batch-goto-within-if-block-behaves-very-strangely)

It seems as it's a bad idéa to combine loops with goto's. So how can I solve my problem?

Comment: There are two issues in your code: 1. you missed to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) although it was required as you write *and* read the same variable within a block of code; 2. `goto :Label` cannot be used within a block/loop as this breaks the block/loop context;

Comment: @aschipfl - Thank you. I'm new to bat-files. I will try the suggested solutions. It seems as they all work. I just need to decide which solution that suits my specific problem best before I accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To use variables that may be changed in loops use `EnableDelayedExpansion` and `!var!` instead of `%var%`
2. Move `:waitfile` to a sub

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    SET filename=fooFile_%%i.txt
        START /B CMD /C CALL createFile.bat fooFile_%%i.txt

    call :waitfile "!filename!"

    ECHO Found file !filename!
)
ECHO All done!
exit /b 0

:waitfile
    ECHO waitforfile: %~1
:waitfile2
    TIMEOUT /T 10 >nul
    IF not EXIST "%~1" goto waitfile2
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Thanks! Accepted this particular answer since it suited my needs best and it was a good fit with my other logic. The other answers worked as well.

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do for %%f in ("fooFile_%%i.txt") do (
        start /b "" cmd /c createFile.bat "%%~ff" 

        2>nul ( 
            break | for /l %%a in (0) do @(<"%%~ff" exit) || ( 
                echo ...waiting for %%~ff
                ping -n 5 localhost >nul 
            ) 
        )

        echo [%%~ff]  found
    )
    ECHO All done!
```

- To avoid enabling delayed expansion only to retrieve the value inside the changed variable, the generated file name is wrapped inside a `for` replaceable parameter (`%%f`)
- The wait loop is executed in a separate `cmd` process (spawned to handle the pipe) that will end when the target file can be read. If the file is not available the `<"%%~ff"` input redirection will fail and the `exit` command will not be executed. If the file is available, then the `exit` command is executed and the loop ends.
- As `timeout` can not be used with a redirected input (wait code is running inside a pipe), it has been replaced with a `ping` to local host
- This test code uses full paths for generated files (`%%~ff` is the full path of the file being pointed by `%%f`). Change it to your needs.

note: just for reference, the `createFile.bat` used for testing was

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    if "%~1"=="" exit /B
    >nul timeout /t 3
    >"%~1" echo testing
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off

for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (call :process %%i
)
ECHO All done!

:: rest of mainline code here

goto :eof

:process
    SET filename=fooFile_%1.txt
    START /B CMD /C CALL createFile.bat fooFile_%1.txt

:waitfile
    ECHO waitforfile: %filename%
    TIMEOUT /T 10 >nul
    IF EXIST %filename% GOTO FoundIt
    goto waitfile

:FoundIt
    ECHO Found file %filename%
    goto :eof
```

There are other problems with your batch - mainly `delayedexpansion` methodology is required if you use the changed value of an environment variable in the loop.