# Batch file for loop has a syntax error

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch for loop with a `The syntax of the command is incorrect` error.
I am reading a file

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a filecnt=1
set /a emptylist=1
for /f "delims=  " %%x in ('type "%execution_list_file%"') do ( 
  set /a emptylist=0
  echo File number !filecnt! >> %logfile% 2>&1
  set /a sleepcnt=0
  set /a found=0

::call :lookup

  set /a filecnt=!filecnt!+1
)
```

My file has a bunch of file paths in it likes this:

```
\\VDI\Prod\Dataloads\PROD\FileName01.csv
\\VDI\Prod\Dataloads\PROD\FileName02.csv
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: change `::call ` to `rem call`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is used for commenting code, `::` is technically a label.

Code blocks do [not behave correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481558/windows-batch-goto-within-if-block-behaves-very-strangely) when they have labels in them, because of how batch parses code.

When you are inside of `for` loops, multiline `if` statements, and other lines of code wrapped in parentheses, you should use `rem` to comment instead.