# Windows batch file: GOTO, DELAYEDEXPANSION issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, goto

See my batch below!

> Expected output: Success
>
> Current output: Success
>
> ```
>             Error
> ```

Any idea, why could be the problem? Without GOTO works as expected.

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION



SET doIt=1

SET callMeAgain=1

if !doIt! == 1 (

    :loop
    if !callMeAgain! == 1 (
        SET callMeAgain=0
        GOTO :loop
    )

    ECHO Success

) ELSE (

    ECHO Error
)


ECHO.

ENDLOCAL

PAUSE
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Windows batch) Goto within if block behaves very strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481558/windows-batch-goto-within-if-block-behaves-very-strangely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `GOTO` breaks any parenthesis block.

A minimal example

```
if 1==1 (
   echo success
   goto :dummy
   :dummy
) ELSE (
   echo ERROR
)
```

After the jump to `:dummy` the batch parser looks at:

```
) ELSE (
   echo ERROR
)
```

The `IF` part is ignored at this point.
The `) ELSE (` part is simply ignored, because a single opening `)` works like a line comment here.